# \verb in csquotes

Tags: verbatim, best-practices, csquotes

The following code gives me an error:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{babel,csquotes}
\begin{document}
\enquote{\verb|foo|}
\end{document}
```

I guess this is the classic "you can't use verbatim material in commands" problem. Is there a solution to this besides writing `\texttt{foo}` or using quotation marks directly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I wrote the [`newverbs`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/newverbs) package with such an application in mind, i.e.\ quote a verbatim text. It provides, beside other things, a `\qverb` macro for quoted verbatim material. It is compatible with [`csquotes`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/csquotes) and will us its start and end quote marks.

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{babel,csquotes}
\usepackage{newverbs}% load after csquotes

% If you want to have automatic nested quotes.
% By default single (inner) quotes are used.
\let\qverbbeginquote\openautoquote
\let\qverbendquote\closeautoquote
% or
%\renewverbcommand{\qverb}{\openautoquote}{\closeautoquote}
\begin{document}
\qverb|foo|

%Compare
\enquote{\texttt{foo}}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

---

If you want to support quoted normal text which includes some verbatim material you could either use `\openautoquote` .. `\closeautoquote` directly, or use a brace group and a macro like this to place the closing quote at the end of the group:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{babel,csquotes}
\newcommand{\genquote}{\openautoquote\bgroup\aftergroup\closeautoquote\aftergroup\egroup}
\begin{document}
{\genquote This is a longer text.

It also include verbatim \verb|foo|.
Etc.}
\end{document}
```

This is also possible in (pseudo-)macro form:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{babel,csquotes}
\newcommand{\genquote}{\openautoquote\bgroup\aftergroup\closeautoquote\let\dummy= }
\begin{document}
\genquote{This is a longer text.

It also include verbatim \verb|foo|.
Etc.}
\end{document}
```

<sub>(Instead of `\dummy` the internal `\@let@token` can be used; then you don't "waste" a macro name.)</sub>

Comment: I would vote for making `\let\qverbbeginquote\openautoquote` and the other default.

Comment: @PatrickGundlach: I was thinking just about this. Originally I used single quotes for verbatim, especially very short ones (1-2 characters) where the double quotes looked to big. However, having the normal quotes as default seem to be more correct. Now, I'm always skeptical about changing the default value of one of my packages. I have to think about it.

Comment: This is of course the easiest way when only `\verb|foo|` needs to be quoted. If the verbatim bit is embedded in a phrase to be quoted, then the environment form seems to be the only way (unless one is satisfied with "saving" the verbatim bit beforehand).

Comment: @egreg: You are totally right. I figured from the example that only a verbatim text should be quotes; especially because I needed this very often in the past in my package manuals. If you need to quote longer text with verbatim included I would use `\openautoquote` and `\closeautoquote` directly instead of defining and using an environment.

Comment: @MartinScharrer Good idea. However there was a missing final space and I'd prefer `\def\genquote#{...}` so that a brace is required: `\genquote x` would lead to *very* obscure errors.

Comment: @egreg: I was thinking also about using `\def\genquote#{...}`. The trailing space probably comes from the dot.

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{babel,csquotes,listings}
\begin{document}
\enquote{\lstinline|foo|}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Without using any packages, a general mechanism for using verbatim material in a context where `\verb` is not allowed is

```
\setbox0\hbox{\verb|fooo|}

\enquote{\usebox0}
```

Note you have to use `\setbox` here not the LaTeX `\sbox` or `\savebox` as they read their argument as macro argument so `\verb` is not allowed.

Comment: There are the `collectbox` and `realboxes` packages which would make this easier, but defeat the purpose of not using a package again.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a "poor man's" environment form (thanks to Martin Scharrer for pointing to the `\openautoquote` command):

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{babel,csquotes}

\newenvironment{inlineenquote}
  {\openautoquote\ignorespaces}
  {\unskip\closeautoquote}
\newenvironment{inlineenquote*}
  {\openinnerquote\ignorespaces}
  {\unskip\closeinnerquote}

\begin{document}

Abc \enquote{XXX} def \enquote*{XXX} ghi

Abc
\begin{inlineenquote}
\verb|XXX|
\end{inlineenquote}
def
\begin{inlineenquote*}
\verb|XXX|
\end{inlineenquote*}
ghi

\end{document}
```

One may find this easier to manage than writing

```
Abc \openautoquote\verb|XXX|\closeautoquote{} def
```

Of course these two forms are more practical over Martin's `\qverb` when the verbatim material is embedded in a phrase and not the only thing to be quoted.